# How many elements do the following sets have?

Tags: linear-algebra

The first set is $$\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing,\{2\}\}\}\}$$ and the other is $\{\mathbb Z \cup \varnothing\}$.

For the first set I guessed 3 elements since $\{\varnothing\}$, $\{\varnothing\}$, and $\{\{\varnothing,\{2\}\}\}$ are three elements, and for the other set my answer was infinitely many elements, but both answers were wrong.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please be careful with the tags you use as well as with the notations. For instance, we do not know what Z is in you question. Please make a full sentence in the body of your post, even if it is repeating the title of your question.
If you do not know how to write in Tex and MathJax, we can provide links and tutorials such as https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Andrei.B Although in this case, the value of $Z$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @Andrei.B already edited, sorry it's my first post over here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I've now edited the post, sorry for the lack of information.

Comment: If you run around my table, you'll see me, then my mother, then my father, then me again. Therefore there are three people at the table: my mother, me and me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{\color{red}{\emptyset},\color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}},\color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}},\color{green}{\{\{\emptyset,\{2\}\}}\}$

Here, the blue $\color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}}$'s are identical and therefore redundant.  One could have been removed.  There are three elements therefore... the red element $\color{red}{\emptyset}$... the blue element $\color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}}$, and the green element $\color{green}{\{\emptyset,\{2\}\}}$.

Remember a few things here... $\color{red}{\emptyset}$ is not equal to $\color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}}$.  The first is a set with zero elements, the emptyset.  The second is a set with one element... that element being the emptyset.  The second is not however *itself* empty.  The "*depth*" is important here and can not be ignored.

Also note, the emptyset is a perfectly valid element of a set.  It just happens to not have anything *inside* of it, but that doesn't stop it from existing itself or from being used as an element in something else.

Finally, remember that repeated elements are redundant and do not change the meaning of the set.  $\{a,a\}$ is equal as a set to $\{a\}$ since every element in the one is an element of the other and vice versa.  Whenever we are talking about the size of a set, we remove any redundancies first.  There do exist other types of objects where we care about and allow repetition... those would be called "*multisets*" but they are irrelevant for the current problem.

So, the answer to the first question is $3$, however not for the reason you stated.

As for the second question, $\Bbb Z\cup \emptyset$ is simply $\Bbb Z$.  Further, do not confuse $\Bbb Z$ which has infinitely many members with $\{\Bbb Z\}$ which has one member... that one member being $\Bbb Z$ itself.  That one member happens to have infinitely sub-members itself, however we are only interested in counting at the top level.  We do not "*flatten*" the sets here.

$\{\Bbb Z\cup \emptyset\}$ has one element, that element being $\Bbb Z$

Comment: +1 nicely and patiently explained.

Comment: Thank you so much, the explanation was perfect!